# deserializing JSON using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm receiving the following error when I attempt to deserialize JSON text:

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0]', line 1, position 3.

The JSON Text validated properly using JSONLint.com, here is the JSON text:

```
[
    [
        {"trackingNo":"R2E2003100011429","eventTime":1479184076000,"eventCode":"INF","activity":"Shipping Information received by Australia Post","location":"","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"R2E2003100011429","eventTime":1479186149000,"eventCode":"INF","activity":"Shipping Information approved by Australia Post","location":"","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"R2E2003100011429","eventTime":1479448620000,"eventCode":"SCN","activity":"Departed facility","location":"","referenceTrackingNo":null}
    ],
    [
        {"trackingNo":"HBF0003142011420","eventTime":1478666798000,"eventCode":"INF","activity":"Shipping Information received by Australia Post","location":"","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"HBF0003142011420","eventTime":1478732453000,"eventCode":"INF","activity":"Shipping Information approved by Australia Post","location":"","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"HBF0003142011420","eventTime":1478932980000,"eventCode":"SCN","activity":"Departed facility","location":"","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"HBF0003142011420","eventTime":1479082255000,"eventCode":"SCN","activity":"Arrived at facility in destination country","location":"","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"HBF0003142011420","eventTime":1479082261000,"eventCode":"CCD","activity":"Cleared by customs","location":"","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"HBF0003142011420","eventTime":1479124118000,"eventCode":"SCN","activity":"Processed through Australia Post facility","location":"CHULLORA NSW","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"HBF0003142011420","eventTime":1479236805000,"eventCode":"SCN","activity":"With Australia Post for delivery today","location":"KINGSGROVE NSW","referenceTrackingNo":null},
        {"trackingNo":"HBF0003142011420","eventTime":1479248135000,"eventCode":"DLD","activity":"Delivered","location":"CARINGBAH NSW","referenceTrackingNo":null}
    ]
]

Here is my code:

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                List<string[]> trackingResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(text);
//    ...Do some stuff...

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you should use is `List<List<SomeObject>>`

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<SomeObject>>>(json);


public class SomeObject
{
    public string trackingNo { get; set; }
    public long eventTime { get; set; }
    public string eventCode { get; set; }
    public string activity { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string referenceTrackingNo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: LB whats the best method to access contents

Comment: For ex., `result[0][0].trackingNo`